# Woocommerce: Exclude products from importing if they have less than two sizes available

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Some products have multiple sizes, for example: "size: S, M, L, XL"

We have the following code in our Custom Code plugin to separate and identify the different sizes:

```
add_filter( 'dfrpswc_filter_attribute_value', 'mycode_add_size_attribute2',     20, 6 );
function mycode_add_size_attribute2( $value, $attribute, $post, $product,  $set, $action ) {
    if ( $attribute == 'pa_maat' ) {
        if ( isset( $product['size'] ) ) {
            $value = mycode_get_size2( $product['size'] );
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Is it possible to only import products that have more than three sizes?

(for example: product with sizes “S, M, XL” will be in the shop, product with sizes “S, M” will not be in the shop)

Thanks,

Solomon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $value is being returned as an array or countable object, you can use the `count()` function such as

```
if (count($value) > 3){
//custom code here
}
```

More information: [Count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Hi Amar B, does your code mean that products with less than 3 sizes will be imported? Shouldn't i use if (count($value) > 3){
//custom code here
} to import products with more than 3 sizes? Thanks!

Comment: I got the above done. Thanks alot! I have one question left. I tried if (count($value) => 3){ //custom code here } to import products that have equal or more than 3 sizes. That give me an error. How should this code look like? Is that the correct way to address equal or more in php (=>)? Thanks!

Comment: @Solomon You're correct, I've modified the code snippet. Also, a simple google for php comparison operators would tell you it's (>=). Glad you got it working in the end.